# How to use Intent to get external image and set as wallpaper

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-wallpaper

I used intent to open gallery of user's phone and now I need to set selected image as wallpaper for my activity.or set image to ImageView on my Activity.not the set as phone's wallpaper.
can somebody help me?
Here's the code I used so far.. i can select image.but nothing happens after that.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Button chooseImg=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseImg);
    chooseImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent img=new Intent();
            img.setType("image/*");
            img.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser
                    (img, "Select Picture"),SELECT_PICTURE);

            Object tag=v.getTag();
            Integer rId=(Integer) tag;
            img.putExtra("bgImage", rId);



            try{
            imgLayout=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgImg1);


            int imgId=img.getExtras().getInt("bgImage");
            imgLayout.setBackgroundResource(imgId);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nope", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement onActivityResult like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE&& resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For setting button background create a BitmapDrawable like this

```
BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap);
```

and for layout you can use  `setBackgroundDrawable` method

Comment: If i need to set this as background for Layout or Button ,How should i do it?

Comment: i cant use context.it shows not found error.and i used setBackgroundDrawable to RelativeLayout.but when i use it,app get crashed. "Unfortunately app has stopped".
whats is the wrong here?im confused

Comment: you can create a context variable and assign  `this` to it

Comment: still if i use layout,app crashes.is this something wrong with i using layouts?
cant they be used to set background?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(4247): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/136980 }} to activity {com.ex.myapp/com.ex.myapp.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 11:39:17.790: E/AndroidRuntime(4247):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3162)
08-29 11:39:17.790: E/AndroidRuntime(4247):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3205)